# Validating data, login system codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

I gotta validate the "username" & "password".

This is my table with the users:

[image]

And here the users:

[image]

The login system must "clasify" those users who are ADMIN users (tipo = 0) and simple users (tipo = 1). Note: ADMIN and simple users have different screens after loging

**I gotta validate that the guy who access is an active member (i got problems with it)**

ESTATUS = 1 IS AN ACTIVE USER

ESTATUS = 0 IS NOT AN ACTIVE USER

**And i do not know how should i validate if a guy did not write anything and he only click on the "login" button (i should not connect to the server to validate it)**

**Here is my code, it works properly.. It validates if the user is an ADMIN or a simple user and if the information written in the login system corresponds to a person in the database.**
**But i do not know how should i do the "ESTATUS" validation and how i should check blank fields without connecting to the server :/**

```
<?php

        Class Login extends CI_Controller{


        public function index(){


           $this->load->view('login_form');


        }

        public function do_login()
        {

            if(isset($_POST['login'])){

                $user=$this->input->post('usuario', true);
                $pass=$this->input->post('contrasena', true);
                $cek = $this->m_login->proceso_login($user,$pass);
                $hasil=count($cek);

                if($hasil > 0){

                    $pelogin =$this->db->get_where('usuarios',array('usuario' => $user, 'contrasena' => $pass))->row();

                    if($pelogin ->tipo == 0){
                        redirect('login/admin');

                    }

                    else{
                    redirect('login/usuario');

                    }



                }
                    redirect('login/index');


            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some [validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form%20validation) before inserting your data into the database:

```
 public function do_login()
        {
         // load the form_validation library
         $this->load->library('form_validation');

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('Your_username_field_name', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|alpha_numeric');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('Your_password_field_name', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');

           // if there is errors
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
            // this will load your form with the errors
               $this->load->view('Login_main');      
         } else {
           // if no errors we will hit the database
            $user=$this->input->post('usuario', true);
            $pass=$this->input->post('contrasena', true);
            $cek = $this->m_login->proceso_login($user,$pass);
            $hasil=count($cek);

            if($hasil > 0){

                $pelogin =$this->db->get_where('usuarios',array('usuario' => $user, 'contrasena' => $pass))->row();

                if($pelogin ->tipo == 0){
                    redirect('login/admin');
                }

                else{
                    redirect('login/usuario');
                }
            }
            redirect('login/index');
        }
    }
```

### **then** in your Login_main view you could add this line of code to echo the errors to see what's going wrong:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

Comment: Mate, it does nt work properly:
When i write a bad username or password it does not show any message or something like that. Also it does not validate if estado=0 or estado=1 :/
https://ideone.com/TVhcff
https://ideone.com/WdIX8C

Comment: I have updated my answer However i really recommend you to take a look at the [validation rules](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form%20validation)

Comment: Dude, it is stillnot working.I mean, it redirect me to the "Admin"/"user"  different screen when i write the username/password. BUT it does not do anything when iclick on "login" with empty fields or when i write wrong usernames/passwords.
I only getthis message:
https://i.gyazo.com/d2b7ed12a47143243f0b0b6fb4ba6761.png

Here is my code:
https://ideone.com/BXAqOW
https://ideone.com/XjYFFZ

Comment: What is your login view path?

Comment: or you mean:
C:\xampp\htdocs\LOGIN-NUEVO\crud\application\views\Login_main

Comment: in Login_main i have my login:
https://i.gyazo.com/86fffa519d6f73bba9d3bd44eb39631b.png

Comment: I have updated my answer and do not forget to add `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` in you `Login_main` to see the validation errors

Comment: Dude, it is not working properly :/
When i write anything in fields username and passwod (i mean dasda and sdfsd) i got a message which says: (The Username field is required. The Password field is required.). It must appears when i click on login with empty files.
If i do not write anything in fields and then i click on login button this error appears:
https://i.gyazo.com/8a6ec28d0d312a67248df2a7932a398f.png

Comment: EDIT: it works when i click when empty fields.. but IT IS NOT working when i write anything that it is not in the database, i got this error:
https://i.gyazo.com/8a6ec28d0d312a67248df2a7932a398f.png

Comment: let's continue our chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139697/discussion-on-answer-by-amr-aly-codeigniter-object-not-found-error)